# Moving page because of a CSS code for moving one text line

Tags: css, wordpress, css-animations

I put CSS code for moving a text line from left to right in a Wordpress website, but now sometimes the whole page is moving in reverse, I mean right to left, by scrolling page up or down. This mostly happen on desktop view. I have no idea what's wrong or what to search and solve it. This is the code I used (from a CSS tutorial):

```css
.bless {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  animation-name: leftToright;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes leftToright {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML so as to create a [mre].

Comment: I just wrote the text in a text block in wordprsss and add bless class as a css class to it. But I can add the code text of wordpress text block

Comment: It was just a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because of the text you are trying to move is going of the section itself. I would suggest you to use `overflow:hidden;` (css) in the wrap div for the text. This will hide the text if it goes outside the container.

Comment: Thank you for your response. At first I did that and yes, in device width smaller than 815px it hide the text but the problem didn't solve. So I removed it.